# Dónde se guardan los archivos guardados por localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una duda de donde se guardan los archivos guardados con localStorage. Adjunto el código utilizado hasta ahora. Muchas gracias a todos espero que me podáis dar una respuesta. Seguro que hay alguna manera de averiguar en donde está la ruta del archivo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="editable" >
            <h2>Escribe tu pedido:</h2>
            <ul contenteditable id="listacompra">
                <li>2 bolsas de patatas</li>
                <li>1 dónut</li>
                <li>4 Kg. de boniatos</li>
            </ul><br><br>
            <input type="button" id="guardar" value="guardar">
        </section>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('guardar').addEventListener('click', guardar);
            recuperarLista();
            function guardar() {
                var contenido = document.getElementById('listacompra').innerHTML;
                localStorage.setItem('lista', contenido);
                alert('Lista guardada');
            }
            function recuperarLista() {
                //LEER la lista del storage
                var lista = localStorage.getItem('lista');
                
                //informar la lista del documento 
                document.getElementById('listacompra').innerHTML = lista;
            }
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hay una pregunta en SO sobre el tema, al ser una pregunta tan directa ya que seria copy/paste no me parece buena idea responder con ella. Te dejo aqúi en enlace a dicha pregunta: [Where the sessionStorage and localStorage stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634058/where-the-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-stored). Aclaro que como es una pregunta directa y son rutas locales no creo que haga falta traducción.

Comment: @Parra te animo a que respondas aquí en SOes, aunque la respuesta exista, no está en nuestra comunidad en español, al final puedes citar la fuente dándole crédito al autor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pregunta Original: [StackOverflow en Ingles - Respuesta de @NatureShade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634058/where-the-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-stored/27612275#27612275)

---

### Firefox

Firefox almacena el localstorage en el archivo `webappsstore.sqlite` en la carpeta *perfil*.

#### Firefox (Windows XP):

```
C:\Archivos de programa\<Usuario de windows>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<carpeta del perfil>\webappsstore.sqlite
```

#### Firefox (Windows Vista y superior):

```
C:\Usuarios\<Usuario de windows>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<carpeta del perfil>\webappsstore.sqlite
```

o:

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<carpeta del perfil>\webappsstore.sqlite
```

#### Firefox en linux:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/<carpeta del perfil>/webappsstore.sqlite
```

#### Firefox en mac:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<carpeta del perfil>/webappsstore.sqlite
```

o:

```
~/Library/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/<carpeta del perfil>/webappsstore.sqlite
```

---

### Chrome

Chrome lo almacena en diferentes archivos dentro de la carpeta `Local Storage`.

#### Chrome en windows:

```
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\
```

#### Chrome en linux:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage/
```

#### Chrome en mac:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/<Profile>/Local Storage/
```

Comunmente:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/
```

---

### Internet explorer:

Comprobado, en mi caso **NO** está aquí. Si alguien conoce la ruta que edite la respuesta.

```
%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStorage
```

---

### Opera

```
C:\Usuarios\Administrador\AppData\Roaming\Opera\Opera\sessions\autosave.win
```

o:

```
C:\Usuarios\Administrador\AppData\Local\Opera\Opera\pstorage\
```

---

### Fuentes de la pregunta Original

- [StackOverflow - Where does firefox store javascript html localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079075/where-does-firefox-store-javascript-html-localstorage)
- [SuperUser - Where does google chrome save localstorage from extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/507536/where-does-google-chrome-save-localstorage-from-extensions)
- [Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md)
- Comprobaciones realizadas por el autor de la pregunta original (Ubuntu 14.10 Firefox y Chrome)
- Comprobaciones propias (Windows 7 Firefox y Chrome)